# Combobox selectedvalue

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox on my form (winforms). In the properties I have set the DisplayMember and the ValueMember. DisplayMember = Name and ValueMember = ID. The Combobox is populated with the following objects:

```
public class MyObj
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

The Name displays fine in the dropdown(so DisplayMember is working) however, when I do:

mycombobox.SelectedValue it is ALWAYS null.

Does anyone know if I've forgotten to do anything?

Comment: where did you check `mycombobox.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: It's on the click event of a button. I have also tried checking it on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox itself but it didn't work there either.

Comment: if you do SelectedIndex or SelectedItem what do you get? can you add the code of how the combobox is configured and populated?

Comment: Try to swap ID and Name: `DisplayMember = ID` and `ValueMember = Name` and see if ID displays fine in the dropdown to make sure your datasource is fine.

Comment: I set DisplayMember = ID and it displays the ID just fine.

Comment: SprintDropDownItem item = (SprintDropDownItem) productBacklogSprintDrop.SelectedItem; <-- This works but I thought ValueMember would stop me needing to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the `DataSource` property. Also make sure that you have to set them in the correct order -

Set them in the following order -

```
1. DisplayMember
2. ValueMember
3. DataSource
```

See this link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/211a46f5-5971-4ea2-a61d-84e389360909

Alternatively you can use the `SelectedItem` property to get the selected `MyObj` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using the SelectedItem property and casting.

Comment: THANK YOU for the order comment! Saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

try SelectedItem

```
MyObj obj = (MyObj)mycombobox.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Has an item been selected? Selected is not always the same as visible. Perhaps you really want to mycombobox.Text.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar mistake. I set DisplayMember and ValueMember, but i set instead of DataSource Items.Insert.